# ListConvolve with Padding -> Fixed?

Tags: list-manipulation, convolution

The built-in function `ImageConvolve` takes a `Padding` option that "specifies what padding to use when extending beyond the original data specified." It has several useful settings, such as:

- $\mathit{val}$: pad with a constant value $\mathit{val}$
- `"Fixed"`: repetitions of the elements on each boundary
- `"Periodic"`: cyclic repetitions of the complete array
- `"Reflected"`: reflections of the array in the boundary
- `"Reversed"`: reversals of the complete array

In principle, `ListConvolve` does exactly the same thing as `ImageConvolve`, just on a (possibly multidimensional) list rather than an image. But surprisingly, it does not accept `Padding` as an option. You can only provide an extra $\mathit{padlist}$ argument with which you can replicate the $\mathit{val}$ and `"Periodic"` settings above. Is there a straightforward way to replicate the effect of the other settings (`"Fixed"`, `"Reflected"`, `"Reversed"`) in `ListConvolve`?

Using `ImageConvolve` sandwiched between `Image` and `ImageData` calls is not an option, because one might be working with symbolic or multidimensional data.

Comment: "surprisingly, it does not accept `Padding` as an option." -probably for new-ish users, I think; `ListConvolve[]`/`ListCorrelate[]` were introduced way before `ArrayPad[]`. If you'll compare those two with `Partition[]`, you'll see a number of similarities.

Answer (score 6):

You can just  apply `ArrayPad` before performing the convolution; it supports all the desired padding forms and more. However, you'll have to adjust the third parameter of `ListConvolve` to get rid of the extra entries in the result.

Comment: Can you elaborate? What would I do with the third parameter?